# Why is my code converting the first number wrong to hexadecimal?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, integer, function-definition

I have this function which receives the number `894867` (`nbr`) and the length `16` (`i`). When I run this code, it writes `=A793` instead of what it should write `DA793`.

```
void ft_transformers(int nbr, int i) {

    char num[100];
    int t;
    int temp;
    int j;

    temp = 0;
    t = 0;
    while (nbr != 0) {
        temp = nbr % i;
        if (num[t] < 10) {
            num[t] = temp + 48; 
        } else {
            num[t] = temp + 55; 
        }         
        nbr /= i;
        t++;
    }

    j = t;
    while (j >= 0) {
        ft_putchar(num[j]);
        j--;
    }   
}
```

Comment: `num[j]` is uninitialized in the first iteration of the 2nd loop because `t++;` is executed at the end of the 1st loop and nothing is written to `num[t]` nor `num[j]` before the 2nd loop.

Comment: `num[t] < 10` is also bad (*undefined behavior*) because `num[t]` is uninitialized at that point.

Comment: @MikeCAT thanks! The solution was to change num[t] for temp as it wasnt yet initialized as you said, you saved my day thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems:

- Instead of `if (num[t] < 10)`, you should be testing `if (temp < 10)`
- instead of hardcoding ASCII values such as `48` and `55`, you should use character constants and expressions `'0'` and `'A' - 10`
- the final loop should decrement `j` **before** accessing the character in the array.
- the behavior is undefined if `i` is `0`, `1` or `-1`.

Here is a modified version:

```
void ft_transformers(int nbr, int base) {

    char num[100];
    int t;
    int j;

    if (base < 2 || base > 36)
        base = 10;

    t = 0;
    while (nbr != 0) {
        int temp = nbr % base;
        if (temp < 10) {
            num[t] = '0' + temp; 
        } else {
            num[t] = 'A' + (temp - 10); 
        }         
        nbr /= base;
        t++;
    }

    j = t;
    while (j > 0) {
        j--;
        ft_putchar(num[j]);
    }
}
```

Note also these shortcomings:

- the function will not output anything if the initial value of `nbr` is zero.
- the function will not output digits if `nbr` is negative.

Here is an improved version:

```
void ft_transformers(int nbr, int base) {

    char num[100];
    int t;
    int j;
    int isneg;

    if (base < 2 || base > 36)
        base = 10;

    isneg = 0;
    t = 0;
    for (;;) {
        int temp = nbr % base;
        if (temp < 0) {
            isneg = 1;
            temp = -temp;
        }
        if (temp < 10) {
            num[t] = '0' + temp; 
        } else {
            num[t] = 'A' + (temp - 10); 
        }         
        t++;
        nbr /= base;
        if (nbr == 0)
            break;
    }

    if (isneg) {
        ft_putchar('-');
    }
    j = t;
    while (j > 0) {
        j--;
        ft_putchar(num[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `do ... while (nbr != 0);` may be better than `for(;;)` and `if (nbr == 0) break;`

Comment: `num[t] = '0' + temp + '0';` why `'0'` is added twice here?

Comment: @MikeCAT: the proposed `do ... while` loop is indeed equivalent, but I never advocate the use of this statement except for `do ... while(0)` in macros. The reason is I have seen too many bugs by both newbie and savvy programmers around this type of control statement. For some reason, delaying the test after the `while` clause tends to make programmers forget some conditions.

Comment: @MikeCAT: adding `'0'` twice was a left over from rewriting the expression :) thanks for noticing

Comment: @MikeCAT: both `for` and `do ... while` are probably excluded by local style rules at the OP's school. What a strange decision! I would personally exclude `do ... while` and `while` instead :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has two errors:

- The condition `num[t] < 10` is wrong. `num[t]` is uninitialized at that point. It should be `temp < 10`.
- The initialization of the second loop `j = t;` is wrong. `t++;` is executed at the end of the first loop and nothing is written to `num[t]` after that before the second loop. It should be `j = t - 1;`.

Also using magic numbers like `48` and `55` should be avoided. They should be `'0'` and `'A' - 10` to make it more clear. (unless your code has chance to be used in environments where character sets that are not compatible to ASCII are used)

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three drawbacks in the function.

For starters instead of the while loop you have to use do-while loop. Otherwise if `nbr` initially is equal to 0 the function will have undefined behavior.

Secondly, in this if statement

```
if (num[t] < 10) {
```

you have to use the variable `temp` instead of `num[t]`

```
if ( temp < 10) {
```

After the while loop the variable t points to after the last digit of the number. So in the first iteration of this loop

```
j = t;
while (j >= 0) {
    ft_putchar(num[j]);
    j--;
}
```

there will be outputted an indeterminate value.

T least you should write

```
j = t;
while (j != 0) {
    ft_putchar(num[--j]);
}
```

Pay also attention to that your function ignores the sign of the original number.

And it is a bad idea to use magic numbers like for example `48` or `55`.

The function can be declared the following way as it is shown in the demonstration program be.low.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void ft_transformers( int nbr, int base ) 
{
    if ( base < 2 || base >  36 )
    {
        printf( "%d\n", nbr );
    }
    else
    {
        char num[8 * sizeof( int )];

        int sign = nbr < 0;

        size_t i = 0;

        do
        {
            int digit = nbr % base;

            if ( sign ) digit = -digit;
            
            if ( digit <  10 )
            {
                digit += '0';
            }
            else
            {
                digit = digit - 10 + 'A'; 
            }

            num[i++] = digit;
        } while ( nbr /= base );

        if ( sign ) putchar( '-' );

        while ( i != 0 ) putchar( num[--i] );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    int nbr = 0;

    ft_transformers( nbr, 16 );

    nbr = 894867;

    ft_transformers( nbr, 16 );

    nbr = -894867;

    ft_transformers( nbr, 16 );
}
```

The program output is

```
0
DA793
-DA793
```

In this declaration of the character array

```
char num[8 * sizeof( int )];
```

instead of the number 8 (the number of bits in a character) you can use the constant CHAR_BIT like

```
char num[CHAR_BIT * sizeof( int )];
```

To do so you need to include the header `<limits.h>`.

Comment: Nitpicking: `char num[8 * sizeof( int )];` is too small for architectures with non 8-bit bytes, use `char num[CHAR_BIT * sizeof( int )];` instead.